# How to combine a bunch of feature points into a blob in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, blob, feature-detection, feature-extraction

I was wondering whether it is possible to combine a bunch of feature points (detected by, lets say `GoodFeaturestoTrack()` ) and create a solid blob out of them?

If not, then how can I ensure detection of a solid object in an image sequence.

Comment: `goodFeaturesToTrack` is used to detect strong corners. If your blob doesn't contain corners, I'm not sure if `goodFeaturesToTrack` is of any use to you. As to "create a solid blob", do you mean `convexHull`?

Comment: Yes. I was refering to convexHull (I wasn't aware that this concept was called convexHull, thank you for that)

Comment: On a slightly digressive note, in which scenarios it is better to use a convexHull in place of a bounded rectangle. I'm assuming both of them are for the purpose of combining feature points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `OpenCV`, you can use [**`convexHull()`**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=convexhull#convexhull) to find the **convex hull** of a point set.

---

**Edit:** if you simply need a bounded rectangle, in `OpenCV`, you can call [**`boundingRect()`**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#boundingrect) instead.

Comment: Thank you. That indeed, has worked. I am able to show a bounded rectangle around the feature points.

However, is it possible to combine these features/points into a single blob?

Comment: @user3079474 What do you mean by `combining features`?

Comment: Joining several feature points (that belong to a single object) into one continuous blob. 

I'm new to OpenCV. Am I drifting towards feature descriptors?

Comment: @user3079474 I am not quite sure here, but they are two different concepts. Convex hull or rectangle is just a matter of region, nothing to do with the features. Perhaps you can concatenate these features together to *serve as* the feature of the blob.

Comment: Exactly, how may I concatenate these features together to serve as the feature of the blob?

Comment: @user3079474 Just *concatenate* them (head-to-tail...). :P